# Parsing JSON with Python - How to access deep elements

Tags: python, json

Hi I am really new to JSON and Python, here is my dilemma, it's been bugging me for two days.
Here is the sample json that I want to parse.

```
{
    "Tag1":"{
"TagX": [
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "01",
    "TagF": null
  },
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "02",
    "TagF": null
  }
],  
"date": "10.03.2017 21:00:00"
    }"
}
```

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
import urllib2

jaysonData = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('URL'))
print jaysonData["Tag1"]
```

How can I get values of TagB and TagC?
When I try to access them with

```
jaysonData = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('URL'))
print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"]["TagB"]
```

The output is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I do this:

```
print jaysonData["Tag1"]
```

The output is:

```
{
"TagX": [
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "01",
    "TagF": null
  },
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "02",
    "TagF": null
  }
],  
"date": "10.03.2017 21:00:00"
    }"
```

I need to reach TagX, TagD, TagE but the below code gives this error:

```
print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"]
```

prints

```
    print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I access TagA to TagF with python? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the returned JSON, the value of `Tag1` is a string, not more JSON. It does appear to be JSON encoded as a string though, so convert that to json once more:

```
jaysonData = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('URL'))
tag1JaysonData = json.load(jaysonData['Tag1'])
print tag1JaysonData["TagX"]
```

Also note that `TagX` is a list, not a dictionary, so there are multiple `TagB`s in it:

```
print [x['TagB'] for x in tag1JaysonData['TagX']]
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

`TagX` is a `list` consisting of 2 dictionaries and `TagB` is a `dictionary`.

```
print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"][0]["TagB"]
```

You need to remove double quotations before and after the curly braces of `Tag1`.

```
{
    "Tag1":{
"TagX": [
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "01",
    "TagF": null
  },
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "02",
    "TagF": null
  }
],  
"date": "10.03.2017 21:00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"][0]["TagB"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @user611811 remove the double quotations also as pointed out by Naresh.

Comment: How can I strip the double quotations with python. This json file is not local and I fetch it every minute. Can you show me at least the way?

Comment: @user611811 Can you give the link of the API or from where you are collecting this data ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Tag1":{
"TagX": [
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "01",
    "TagF": null
  },
  {
    "TagA": "A",
    "TagB": 1.6,
    "TagC": 1.4,
    "TagD": 3.5,
    "TagE": "02",
    "TagF": null
  }
],  
"date": "10.03.2017 21:00:00"
    }
}
```

You have to remove double qoutation before curly bracket of Tag1. I have removed in above sample.

and acess like this.

```
print jaysonData["Tag1"]["TagX"][0]["TagA"]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. But this is a live json data feed from another source. I need to parse this realtime. How can I remove this in my code after jaysonData = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('URL'))

Comment: If you can't change response then do again res = json.load(jaysonData["Tag1"])

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider what values your about to access e.g a dict or list ?
You always access dict element by key and list element by index.

to remove the quotes you can do after reading data from url.

```
import ast
JsonData = ast.literal_eval(jaysonData["Tag1"])
JsonData["Tagx"][0]["TagB"]
```